# Attributing app name when sharing via share dialog in ios Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been banging my head against this for days - all I want to do is share an image that's created in my iOS app on Facebook, and have it in some way credited to the app.

I can't put in any content because they don't allow it - I could add a banner to the bottom of the image but that would spoil the experience a bit.  All I really want is it to say the name of my app along with the share - but I'm having a devil of a time getting it to work.

I can get a share working really easily, by including the relevant SDK files and doing this:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image =_imgMainImage.image;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content=[[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc]init];
content.photos=@[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

but when the share appears on Facebook, it's either attributed to iOS or nothing at all.

The only way I've found that I can actually get it to attribute my app is to use FBSDKShareAPI, after ensuring the user is logged in.  For this I need to get the user to log in and grant me publish permissions, and for that I need to get my app approved by facebook etc - all for something that as far as I can tell shouldn't be necessary.

Am I crazy to think that it should attribute my app if I use FBSDKShareDialog?  Or is it by design that it does not, and I need to do it in the more roundabout way with login and FBSDKShareAPI or the other graph methods?  The former would be a far easier implementation and a better user experience, if only it would work!

I've got the correct stuff in my info.plist (which I think is borne out by the fact that it correctly attributes the app in the case of the FBSDKShareAPI approach).

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: the closest I have come to an answer on this is someone on the facebook developer group that seemed to suggest that share dialog shares would never attribute the app, because it *IS* the user who is sharing, not the app.  Does anyone know if that's the case?

Comment: You are correct in that. Attribution will only be shown if you use the API to publish a post. Not using the Share Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the app name show up in the post on Facebook you have to share it doing something like this:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
sharePhoto.caption = @"Some caption";
sharePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_photo.jpg"];

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[sharePhoto];

[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Make sure you set the "public_actions" permission when the user logs into your app.